# how to store connectionstring on serverside per user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, connection-string

Each user for my asp.net web app will have their own connection to a database that is specific to them. This is because the site will be used by all customers but there will be multiple databases in order to keep their data seperate (compliance with regulations).

Is storing the connection string in a session variable (in sql not in proc) acceptable or can I extend the aspmembershipprovider to hold this information. Surely if I extend the membershipprovider it will just end up in sql or memory anyway depending on the approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've decided that you want to store the connection per-user, I don't see any reason to do anything more complicated than storing it as part of the membership record, and caching it in the session.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I've heard people are trying to get away from using session variables but maybe I've confused that with asp.net viewstate.

Comment: ViewState in this case would indeed be bad - it's transmitted to the client.  Session remains on the server.